# Problem with strcat() overwriting my string

Tags: c, operating-system, posix

I'm writing my own shell, and seem to have some kind of problem with strcat() overwriting a string unexpectedly.

The problem is when trying to execute a file in the local directory. The second value in the path it should search is '.' and the first is /bin, but when appending the command to /bin for the absolute path to give to `execlp()` the period is overwritten by the command as well.  I know the `MYPATH` thing is strange and that it's weird to separate by #s, but that is irrelevant to the issue.

I put some useful `printf()` statements in if you want to run it to see what I'm talking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void execute(char**, int, char**, int);

int main (){
  char *command, *mypath, *buffer, *arglist[1024], *pathlist[1024], **ap;
  buffer = malloc(1024);
  int loop = 1;

  while (loop == 1){
    int argnum = 0, pathnum = 0;
    mypath = malloc(1024);
    if(getenv("MYPATH") == NULL)
      strcpy(mypath, "/bin#.");
    else
      strcpy(mypath, getenv("MYPATH"));
    printf("myshell$ ");
    command = readline("");

    if(strcmp(command, "exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
      return 0;

    if(strcmp(command, "") == 0)
      continue;

    /*Tokenizes Command*/
    for(ap = arglist; (*ap = strsep(&command, " \t")) != NULL;){
      argnum++;
      if(**ap != '\0')
    if(++ap >= &arglist[1024])
      break;
    }

    /*Tokenizes Path*/
      for(ap = pathlist; (*ap = strsep(&mypath, "#")) != NULL;){
    pathnum++;
      if(**ap != '\0')
    if(++ap >= &pathlist[1024])
      break;
      }
      execute(pathlist, pathnum, arglist, argnum);
  }
  return 0;
}

void execute(char *pathlist[], int pathnum, char *arglist[], int argnum){
  pid_t pid;
  int i;
  int found = 0;
  struct stat buf;
  for(i = 0; i < pathnum; i++){
    if (found == 1)
      break;
    printf("pathlist[0]: %s\n", pathlist[0]);
    printf("pathlist[1]: %s\n", pathlist[1]);
    strcat(pathlist[i], "/");
    strcat(pathlist[i], arglist[0]);
    printf("Pathlist[0] after strcat: %s\n", pathlist[0]);
    printf("Pathlist[1] after strcat: %s\n", pathlist[1]);
    if(stat(pathlist[i], &buf) == 0){
      found = 1;
      pid = fork();
      if(pid == -1)
    printf("Error: Fork Failed\n");
      else if(pid == 0){
    if(argnum == 0)
      execlp(pathlist[i], arglist[0], (char *) NULL);
    else if(argnum == 1)
      execlp(pathlist[i], arglist[0], arglist[1], (char *) NULL);
    else if(argnum == 2)
      execlp(pathlist[i], arglist[0], arglist[1], arglist[2], (char *) NULL);
    else if(argnum == 3)
      execlp(pathlist[i], arglist[0], arglist[1], arglist[2], (char *) NULL);
      }
      else if(strcmp(arglist[argnum-1], "&") != 0){
    wait(NULL);
      }
    }
    else if(stat(pathlist[i], &buf) == -1 && i == pathnum-1 && found == 0)
      printf("Error: Command '%s' not found.\n", arglist[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should really lookup the `execvp` function. Writing a different `execlp` call for each possible number of arguments, while possible, is incredibly ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsep()` does not create an independent copy of the token it returns.  It modifies the original string, replacing the delimiter (in this case, the `'#'` character) with a `'\0'`, and returns a pointer that points to the beginning of the token within the original string.

This means that your `pathlist[]` pointers all point within the string pointed to by `mypath` - at the point where you call `execute()`, it looks like this:

```
               '/'   'b'   'i'   'n'   '\0'  '.'   '\0'
                ^                             ^
mypath ---------/                             |
                ^                             |
pathlist[0] ----/                             |
                                              |
pathlist[1] ----------------------------------/

pathlist[2] (null)
```

You can now see why you observe the behaviour you do - when you call `strcat()` on `pathlist[0]`, it starts overwriting that array, beginning at the first `'\0'`.  `pathlist[1]` remains pointing at the same location, but the contents of the string at that location have been overwritten by the `strcat()`.

In the `execute()` function, you shouldn't try to directly concatenate onto `pathlist[i]`.  Instead, construct a new string in a temporary location:

```
char execpath[4096];

if (snprintf(execpath, sizeof execpath, "%s/%s", pathlist[i], arglist[0]) >= sizeof execpath) {
    /* Path was too long, handle the error */
}

if (stat(execpath, &buf) == 0) {
```

Comment: That's interesting and makes perfect sense as to why I was getting the bug.  I did end up using a temporary string and got it working, but now I know why it was doing it.  Thanks a lot this is a really great explanation and a perfect answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I haven't tested your code or even read it very carefully, but I'd recommend dropping `strcat` entirely. It's unsafe because it may write past the end of a buffer without notice.

You might want to define some safe string functions and use those instead:

```
char *xstrdup(char const *s)
{
    char *copy = strdup(s);
    if (copy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot copy string: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    return copy;
}

char *xstrcat(char *s, char const *append)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s) + strlen(append) + 1;
    size_t news = realloc(s, len);
    if (news == NULL) {
        free(s);
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot append strings: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    strcat(news, append);
    return news;
}
```

Comment: xstrcat() is b0rken, it doesn't strcat() to the new memory, but it does return it.

Comment: @unwind: good point, almost fell into the trap I warn about :)